# Where is this hidden computer name coming from?

Tags: windows, hostname, amazon-ami, ssrs

**Environment:**
I am baking Amazon Machine Images with SQL Reporting Services (SSRS) installed. The Windows Server 2016 machine is joined to the domain and its computer name is changed AFTER install.

**Problem:**
When I open SSRS Configuration Manager it shows the correct computer name:

[image]

However, if I set the Service Account it shows the original AWS Computer Name:

[image]

**Troubleshooting:**

1) I looked everywhere in the Registry. Its not there! **EC2AMAZ-DPNS3JK** is not there!

2) I took a Process Monitor trace opening SSRS Config Manager and confirmed its using the expected registry key:

[image]

3) I thought it might be kept in the SSRS database (master, msdb, temp, etc) and searched all tables. The only reference to it is with some upgrade history:

[image]

4) I searched the disk drive just encase it was in a Hosts file or something and no results.

**Question:**

Where is this value EC2AMAZ-DPNS3JK coming from?
Is it hidden in some Registry Application Hive or something?

Pulling my hair out on this one and would appreciate suggestions. Thanks.

**Update:**

The comments were right so I changed the SQL Instance name. However, changing the SQL Instance name still doesn't fix it!!

[image]

Comment: You’re asking about the service instance name not the computer name. Those are two different things. Check here: https://sqldbpool.com/2008/09/03/how-to-change-sql-server-instance-name/

Comment: The right way to do this is to use a sysprepped image. Barring that, you need to rename your SQL instance(s) after renaming the computer. - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ami-create-standard.html - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sysprep-create-install-ec2-windows-amis/

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: Regarding your edit, have you tried rebooting the server after making the change?

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this is to use a sysprepped image. Barring that, you need to rename your SQL instance(s) after renaming the computer.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ami-create-standard.html

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sysprep-create-install-ec2-windows-amis/

Answer (score 0):

I had to call MS support and with their help we worked it out, solution on Stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/55998961/495455

Comment: What's it doing there?

Comment: @MichaelHampton it renames the SSRS instance using the rsconfig.exe utility, quite difficult to find and I got notified > 1000 views...